# The this function to open a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a simple script. That show and hide a div. But i have a problem with "this".

This is my script:

```
var accordion = $(".accordion"),
        content = $(".accordion .content"),
        button  = $(".accordion .btn-1");

    $(button, this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(content, this).show();
    });
```

This is my html

```
<div class="accordion">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x130" width="200" height="130" alt="">

    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod

        </p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" title="More" class="btn-1">More</a>
</div>
```

But i have a lot of that divs. Now, when i click on the btn-1. All of the accordions going open. How can i fix that? And how can i closed the content by clicking the btn-1.

Thank for helping!!

Comment: What is the intent behind `$( $(".accordion .btn-1"), this )`? It doesn't make sense to have a selector context when passing jQuery object to jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to open the corresponding `.content` element when a "button" is clicked. This can be easily solved using [*DOM traversal* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/):

```
$(".accordion .btn-1").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     // find the button's sibling with class 'content' and show it
     $(this).siblings('.content').show();

     // if you want to toggle the visibility, use .toggle instead
     $(this).siblings('.content').toggle();

     // if the structure is more complex, find the corresponding '.accordion'
     // element first and then search for the '.content' element
     $(this).closest('.accordion').find('.content').toggle();
});
```

I recommend to read the [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Thank for you help! It works now. I gone a read the tutorials for jQuery, thanks for the tip.

Last question. What is must do. To change the click effect. To a slidedown and slideup effect?

Comment: You mean to change the show effect I assume. You can use `slideToggle`: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/.

Comment: Yeah that works. Do you know of the slideToggle. Works in all the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is a bit strange, I think what you're trying to do is

```
var content = $(".accordion .content"),
    button  = $(".accordion .btn-1");

button.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    content.show();
});
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
The intent behind your use of `this` is a bit odd.

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem. Any button click will open all accordions.

Comment: `button  = $(".accordion .btn-1");`; just btn-1, but I see your point.

Comment: Seems strange that you would have multiple button #1, but, yes it is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

On button-click, walk up the DOM to the ancestor with class 'accordian' via  .closest(),
Then find the item with class 'content' inside.

```
$(,'.btn-1').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault():
$(this).closest('accordian').find('.content').show();
}
```

That makes the DOM-positionING of btn-1 and content relative to each other within the accordian to be irrelevant -- they wont' have to be siblings -- in case you need to move them around inside the accordian for some reason..